# How to set ("check") all radio buttons with identical classes using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, radio-button, checked

I wish to set all radio buttons using jQuery. My jQuery only sets the very last one in the group.

**HTML**

```
<p class="navbar-text navbar-right" style="margin:-4px 0 0 0">
<input id="serviceProximity-07-1" name="serviceProximity" type="radio" value="1"><label for="serviceProximity-07-1" style="color:#fff;padding-left:0.5em;padding-right:2.0em">In-Area (Svc Group)</label>
<input id="serviceProximity-07-0" name="serviceProximity" type="radio" value="0"><label for="serviceProximity-07-0" style="color:#fff;padding-left:0.5em;padding-right:2.0em">Out-of-Area (Svc Group)</label>
<input id="serviceProximity-07-X" name="serviceProximity" type="radio" value="X"><label for="serviceProximity-07-2" style="color:#fff;padding-left:0.5em;padding-right:2.0em">Clear (Svc Group)</label>
</p>


<tbody>

<tr>
<th scope="row">V1</th>
<td>Description 1</td>
<td><input class="07-1" id="locationProximity-129-1" name="locationProximity" type="radio" value="1"> <label for="locationProximity-129-1">In-Area</label></td>
<td><input class="07-0" id="locationProximity-129-0" name="locationProximity" type="radio" value="0"> <label for="locationProximity-129-0">Out-of-Area</label></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th scope="row">S1</th>
<td>Description 2</td>
<td><input class="07-1" id="locationProximity-234-1" name="locationProximity" type="radio" value="1"> <label for="locationProximity-234-1">In-Area</label></td>
<td><input class="07-0" id="locationProximity-234-0" name="locationProximity" type="radio" value="0"> <label for="locationProximity-234-0">Out-of-Area</label></td>
</tr>

</tbody>
```

**JavaScript/jQuery**

```
<script>

  $( "input[name='serviceProximity']" ).on( 'change', function() {
    //console.log( 'serviceProximity Changed!' );
    //console.log( $(this).val() );
    //console.log( $(this).attr('id') );
    var arr = $(this).attr('id').split('-');
    //console.log( arr[1] );
    //console.log( arr[2] );
    if( arr[2] == '1' ) $( '.' + arr[1] + '-1' ).prop( 'checked', true ); // ONLY SETS LAST ITEM IN THE STACK
    else if( arr[2] == '0' ) $( '.' + arr[1] + '-0' ).prop( 'checked', true ); // ONLY SETS LAST ITEM IN THE STACK
    else {
       $( '.' + arr[1] + '-1' ).prop( 'checked', false ); // THIS WORKS BUT NOT SURE IF IT IS ONLY CLEARING LAST ITEM IN STACK DUE TO ISSUE ABOVE
       $( '.' + arr[1] + '-0' ).prop( 'checked', false ); // THIS WORKS BUT NOT SURE IF IT IS ONLY CLEARING LAST ITEM IN STACK DUE TO ISSUE ABOVE
    }
  });

</script>
```

The objective is the check all "in-area"'s based on the check in `serviceProximity`, to check all of the "out-of-area"'s based on the check in `serviceProximity`, and clear all checks when Clear is checked.

**Amended:**

Tried prepending "`sg-`" to the target class in case javascript/jquery did not like classes starting with a numeric but that did not do the trick.

[Started a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pz5w98o4/)

Comment: You should consider using `data-` attributes to your HTML to handle your matching, rather than encoding data into your ids. Makes it much easier to figure out what part you want where.

Comment: You can only have 1 radio button selected at a time. If you want to be able to select multiple ones, they need to be checkboxes.

Comment: Hmm, not clear on your comment @blackandorangecat. Are you saying there is no possible way to use jQuery to auto-check a series of radio buttons?

Comment: Ok, thanks @MikeMcCaughan...I'll tweak my markup and script and see if that gets me where I want to be.

Comment: @H.Ferrence Correct. By definition radio buttons only allow one in each "group" to be `selected`. Because they all have the same name (`locationProximity`), only 1 can be selected at a time.

Comment: Oh, got it @blackandorangecat -- totally did not see that `name` was the same throughout. I just need to make that unique through the stack. Classic forest & trees syndrome...That will do the job -- I know it will.

Comment: Yep...that did it @blackandorangecat .. totally "my bad".

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to change the `name` attribute of the groups of radio buttons because at any time only one radio button among a group of radio buttons with the same name can be selected. In this case the last one because the prop is changed on it the last.

```
<tr>
  <th scope="row">V1</th>
  <td>Description 1</td>
  <td><input class="07-1" id="locationProximity-129-1" name="locationProximity1" type="radio" value="1"> <label for="locationProximity-129-1">In-Area</label></td>
  <td><input class="07-0" id="locationProximity-129-0" name="locationProximity1" type="radio" value="0"> <label for="locationProximity-129-0">Out-of-Area</label></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <th scope="row">S1</th>
  <td>Description 2</td>
  <td><input class="07-1" id="locationProximity-234-1" name="locationProximity2" type="radio" value="1"> <label for="locationProximity-234-1">In-Area</label></td>
  <td><input class="07-0" id="locationProximity-234-0" name="locationProximity2" type="radio" value="0"> <label for="locationProximity-234-0">Out-of-Area</label></td>
</tr>
```